# jQuery expecting a number for a text input on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nan

I am trying to call a custom API with a jQuery AJAX call, but I am getting the following error:

> The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

I have identified that the problem is from an input that has the value dynamically changed based on the value of another input. The way this is set up is that I have a select field that once selected updates the problem input with the ID of the item that was selected.

When I change the problem `input` to a `type="number"` the error goes away, but because of the `type="number"` the string value ID (here is an example of the ID `'5be25be44d0f9c40d93930ab'`) does not get set to the value of the input because it is not a number. The input should be of `type="text"` but when I try to make the AJAX call the error occurs. Not sure what the issue is or how to fix it. I have included a picture of the full error.

---

**Here is the HTML**

```
//This is the 'select' input.
<div class="ui fluid icon dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="malts[malt1][name]">
    <div class="default text">Variety</div>
    <div id="fw-malt-list" class="menu fw-malt-list">
        <div class="item>...</div>
        <div class="item>...</div>
    </div>
</div>

//This is the problem input
<input id="fw_malt1_id" type="text" name="malts[malt1][id]">
```

---

**Here is the JS**

```
let formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/p/app/api/maltcalc',
     data: formData,
     async: true,
     success: function(data) {}
```

[image]

Comment: _"problem is from an input that has the value dynamically changed based on the value of another input"_ show the code that does this, you are probably setting / creating the value incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I figured out what the issue was with my code. Code that was running on the server had errors because I had updated the input names at some point and so the calculation could not be calculated correctly. The error/exception in the console was from the successful response and then trying to update input values that returned from the server as NaN.